# Error saying setAttribute is null JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, npm, webpack

Im still new to JS, with that being said I am trying to make a task list webpage where a user can submit projects and in those projects have a task list each with a due date to be completed by.

I used UUID v4 in order to generate an ID tag for projects & tasks however when trying to set the ID tag to a project or task the setAttribute function is returning null. I have quite a few JS files and Im using npm and webpack to manage it.

Relevant JS and HTML below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To Do</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <!-- project side bar panel -->
        <div class="proj-panel">
            <h3 class="proj-header">Projects</h3>
            <div class="proj-container">
                <!-- projects in here -->
                <div class="project">Starter Project</div>
            </div>               
            <div class="add-proj-container">
                <div class="add-box">
                    <span role="button" class="+ project-link" id="add-project-bttn">+</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- main content container -->
        <div class="main-panel">
            <div class="proj-main-container">
                <div class="proj-info-container">
                    <div class="proj-info">
                        <div class="proj-info-name">Starter Project</div>
                        <div class="proj-info-description">test description</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="proj-icon-container">
                        <div class="icon-box">
                            <img role="button" src="../src/assests/imgs/folder-edit-outline.svg" class="proj-edit-icon">
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon-box">
                            <img role="button" src="../src/assests/imgs/trash-can-outline.svg" class="proj-trash-icon">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Need a way to edit proj info after adding  -->
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="task-container">
                <!-- daily tasks will go in here -->
                <div class="task">
                    <div class="task-content">
                        <div class="task-area">
                            <div class="checkmark-proj"></div>
                            <div class="task-name">Example task</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="task-area">
                            <div class="due-date"> in 0 days</div>
                            <!-- need forum pop up on edit button -->
                            <img src="../src/assests/imgs/pencil-outline.svg" class="edit-task">
                            <img src="../src/assests/imgs/trash-can-outline.svg" class="delete-task">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="add-task-container">
                <div class="add-box">
                    <span role="button" class="+ project-link" id="task-add">+</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- forum for add project & and task down here -->
        <div id="add-proj-container">
            <form class="forum-container" id="add-proj-forum">
                <h2>New Project</h2>
                <div class="input-content">
                    <input type="text" id="proj-name" name="proj-name" required placeholder="Enter project name here">
                </div>
                <div class="forum-bttns">
                    <button type="submit" id="add-proj-forum-bttn" class="btn">Add Project</button>
                    <button type="button" id="close-add-proj-forum-bttn" class="btn cancel">Close</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- Add task forum -->
        <div id="add-task-forum-container">
            <form class="forum-container" id="add-task-forum">
                <h2> New Task</h2>
                <div class="input-content">
                    <label for="task-name">
                        <b>Task Name</b>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" id="task-name" name="task-name" required placeholder="Write the task name here...">
                </div>
                <div class="row-container">
                    <div class="input-content">
                        <label for="task-due-date">
                            <b>Due Date</b>
                        </label>
                        <input type="date" id="task-due-date" required name="task-due-date">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-content">
                        <label for="task-project">
                            <b>Project</b>
                        </label>
                        <select name="task-project" id="task-project">
                            <option value="Inbox" selected>Inbox</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="forum-bttns">
                        <button type="submit" id="add-task-forum-bttn" class="btn">Add Project</button>
                        <button type="button" id="close-add-task-forum-bttn" class="btn cancel">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>


    </div>

</body>

<script defer src="./main.js"></script>
<!-- Templates to be copied -->

<template id="project-template">
    <div class="proj-info-container">
        <div class="proj-info">
            <div class="proj-info-name"></div>
            <div class="proj-info-description"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="proj-icon-container">
            <div class="icon-box">
                <img role="button" src="../src/assests/imgs/folder-edit-outline.svg" class="proj-edit-icon">
            </div>
            <div class="icon-box">
                <img role="button" src="../src/assests/imgs/trash-can-outline.svg" class="proj-trash-icon">
            </div>
        </div>
</template>
<template id="task-template">
    <div class="task">
        <div class="task-content">
            <div class="task-area">
                <div class="checkmark-proj"></div>
                <div class="task-name">Example task</div>
            </div>
            <div class="task-area">
                <div class="due-date"> in 0 days</div>
                <!-- need forum pop up on edit button -->
                <img src="../src/assests/imgs/pencil-outline.svg" class="edit-task">
                <img src="../src/assests/imgs/trash-can-outline.svg" class="delete-task">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

</html>
```

JS index file:

```
import './css/style.css'
import MainModel from './sections/model/mainModel'
import MainView from './sections/view/mainView'
import MainController from './sections/maincontroller'

const model = new MainModel()
const view = new MainView()
const controller = new MainController(model,view)
```

JS file with the issue:

```
export default class ProjectView{

    constructor(element, projectModel){
        this.element = element
        this.model = projectModel
        this.id = projectModel.id
        this.name = projectModel.name
    }
    get projectName(){
        return this.element.querySelector('proj-name') 
       
    }
    get id(){
        return this.element.getAttribute('id')
        
    }
    get deleteBttn(){
        return this.element.querySelector('proj-trash-icon')
    }
    get editBttn(){
        return this.element.querySelector('proj-edit-icon')
    }
    set id(value){
        this.element.setAttribute("id", value)
        
    }
    set name(value){
        this.projectName.textContent = value
    }

}
```

The error occurs when setAttribute is called on set id(value)

where the ID tag is being generate:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export default class Project
{
  constructor(name)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = uuidv4();
    // console.log(this.id); 
  }
}
```

Im not sure what other files would be necessary

The exact error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')"
I want to retrieve the ID generated by UUID and then apply it to a project thats generated in a seperate JS file.

```
    import TaskView from './taskView'
import ProjectView from './projectView'

export default class MainView{
    getByID(id){
        return document.getElementById(id)
    }
    toggleAddTaskForumVisibility(visible, id)
    {
        const displayValue = visible ? 'block' : 'none';
        this.getByID(id).style.display = displayValue;
        
    }

    toggleFilterVisiblity(visible, id){
        const displayValue = visible ? 'grid' : 'none';
        this.getByID(id).style.display = displayValue
    }

    getAddProjectForumElementValueByName(elementName){
        return this.getByID('add-proj-forum').elements[elementName].value
    }
    getAddTaskForumElementValueByName(elementName){
        return this.getByID('add-task-forum').elements[elementName].value
    }
    resetAndCloseForumByID(forumID,forumContainerID){
        this.getByID(forumID).reset()
        this.toggleAddTaskForumVisibility(false,forumContainerID)
    }
    appendTaskItem(item){
        let templateContent = this.getByID('task-template').content
        let taskItemElementClone = templateContent.cloneNode(true).querySelector('div')
        let taskItemView = new TaskView(taskItemElementClone, item)
        this.getByID('task-container').append(taskItemView.element)

        return taskItemView
    }

    appendProject(item){
        let templateContent = this.getByID('project-template')
        let projectDivElementClone = templateContent.cloneNode(true).querySelector("div");
        let projectView = new ProjectView(projectDivElementClone, item);
        this.getByID('proj-container').append(projectView.element);


        let option = document.createElement('option')
        option.value = item.element
        option.text = item.element
        option.id = `checkbox-${item.id}`
        this.getByID('task-project').appendChild(option)
        return projectView
    }
    fillAddForumWhenEdit(taskItemView){
        this.getByID('add-task-forum').elements['task-name'].value = taskItemView.model.name
        this.getByID('add-task-forum').elements['task-due-date'].value = taskItemView.model.dueDate
        this.getByID('add-task-forum').elements['task-project'].value = taskItemView.model.project

    }
    updateTaskItem(element){
        let taskItemToUpdate = this.getByID(element.id)
        new TaskView(taskItemToUpdate,element.model)
    }
    updateTaskItemAfterProjectDeleted(element){
        let taskItemToUpdate = this.getByID(element.id)
        new TaskView(taskItemToUpdate,element)
    }

}
```

Comment: *"the setAttribute function is returning null"* - More accurately, it [returns `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).  But why is that a problem?  Can you clarify?  In the title you state that `setAttribute` **is** `null`, in the question you claim that it **returns** `null`, and then claim that `id` "is null".  What actual problem are you observing?

Comment: `setAttribute()` doesn't return anything. It just changes the attribute as requested.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: FYI, you can just use `this.element.id`, you don't need to use `getAttribute()` or `setAttribute()`.

Comment: I shouldve been more clear the exact error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')"

Comment: That means that `this.element` is null. Make sure that `this` is what you expect it to be.

Comment: @Sinned: Given the code shown, that would mean `this.element` is `null`.  When you debug, is that the case?  What value do you expect `this.element` to have and why?  Can you update this to a [mcve] which demonstrates?

Comment: @David ahhh lemme check this.element

Comment: You haven't shown how you use the ProjectView class.

Comment: @Barmar the ProjectView file is the file with the issue, the second one.

Comment: @David The element in this case would be the project the user has submited through a forum the forum simply asks for a name of the project, to which is want to use UUID to attach an ID to it. The reason being is im using the local storage function in webpack i believe

Comment: I know, but you haven't shown how you use it. I don't see any `new ProjectView()` calls anywhere.

Comment: @Barmar I added the mainView file which calls for Project View

Comment: So, I'm not going to re-edit your question, but you don't need to title your edits; we can see the edit history of the question whenever we want (clicking on the "edited N units ago" link). You should edit your question to make it as if it had the information required from the beginning. Also, the word is spelled "I'm", a contraction of I and am.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Fair enough, I didnt know that. I dont see how correcting "Im" is important tho.

Comment: The site, as the [tour] mentions, prides itself on having high quality questions and answers. Having "txt-spk" littered throughout our site lowers that perceived quality. I mean, how do you want to present yourself to potential employers? As someone well-spoken, who takes the time to proofread their text before publishing? Or not? Up to you.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I get that, just didnt think it applied to  "Im" specifically, since its generally understood that its a contraction. I also highly doubt an employer would see this as a huge negative. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling setAttribute, you can add a check to see if `this.element` is `null`.

```
if (this.element) {
    this.element.setAttribute("id", value);
} else {
    console.error("Element is null. Cannot set attribute.");
}
```